# Default value for create_table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm populating a Table I created by using a rake from a gem's response. However, records without an image_url return 'nil'. How can I set it so the rake automatically replaces 'nil' with a fixed value?

```
namespace :cards do 
    desc "Create cards"
    task :create_cards => :environment do
        cards = MTG::Card.where(page: 50).where(pageSize: 50).all
        cards.each do |card|
            Card.create(name: card.name,multiverse_id: card.multiverse_id, manaCost: card.mana_cost, cmc: card.cmc, cardtype: card.type, rarity: card.rarity, set: card.set, setName: card.set_name, text: card.text, flavor: card.flavor, artist: card.artist, number: card.number, power: card.power, toughness: card.toughness, layout: card.layout, image_url: card.image_url, watermark: card.watermark, original_text: card.original_text, original_type: card.original_type)
        end
    end
end
```

I'm wondering if this is something I need to do in the Controller? The Controller is only:

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I tried using :default => "MyValue" but it didn't work - I assume since null /= NIL

Welcome any input.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a check if the value is there during the loop?  For example:

```
namespace :cards do 
    desc "Create cards"
    task :create_cards => :environment do
        cards = MTG::Card.where(page: 50).where(pageSize: 50).all
        card.image_url.blank? ? image_url = 'fixed_val' : image_url = card.image_url
        cards.each do |card|
            Card.create(name: card.name,multiverse_id: card.multiverse_id, manaCost: card.mana_cost, cmc: card.cmc, cardtype: card.type, rarity: card.rarity, set: card.set, setName: card.set_name, text: card.text, flavor: card.flavor, artist: card.artist, number: card.number, power: card.power, toughness: card.toughness, layout: card.layout, image_url: image_url, watermark: card.watermark, original_text: card.original_text, original_type: card.original_type)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Oh I didn't even think about that. Shouldn't I put it in the cards.each? Just before the Card.create?

Comment: Yep - Placing that logic in the .each worked perfectly. Thanks!